# Remove long key value pairs in jsonb column in postgres with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am using a materialized view to merge an query 3 json columns because I want to query all of them together with 1 GIN index. The view looks similar to this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS test_materialized_view AS
SELECT t1.id, (t1.data1 || t1.data2 || COALESCE(t2.data1, '{}'::jsonb)) "data"
FROM table_1 t1 LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON (...);
```

Now it can happen that there are longer key value pairs in the json data which I never want to query and which can be stored 1000 of times because they are in t2.data1 . Is it possible to filter the merged json and only include key value pairs with a length less than x characters? Does this even make a difference / reduce saved data?

I dont know the json keys of these fields. I basically just want to remove all key value pairs which are longer than x characters or array / nested objects but did not really find a good way to do this in postgres

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to "hide" `t2.data1` if the _total_ length of `data1` exceeds 256 characters or remove all key/value pairs from the JSONB where the values exceed 256 characters. Btw: why 256? There is no magic performance or storage improvement for strings shorter than 256 characters  compared to e.g. 258 or 261 characters.

Comment: I want to remove the key value pair. 256 is just any random number which makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this. You will need to write your own.

Something along the lines:

```
create function remove_long_values(p_input jsonb, p_maxlen int)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select coalesce(jsonb_object_agg(e.ky, e.val), '{}')
  from jsonb_each(p_input) as e(ky,val) 
  where length(e.val::text) <= p_maxlen;
$$
language sql
immutable
parallel safe;
```

The above does **not** deal with nested key/value pairs! It only checks this on the first level.

Then use it in the query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS test_materialized_view 
AS
SELECT t1.id, t1.data1 || t1.data2 || remove_long_values(t2.data1,250) as "data"
FROM table_1 t1 
  LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON (...);
```